# Package that Excludes Interacted Items and Return Top N Recommendations?

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I am interested to understand why there seems to not be a lot of implementations in existing recommender system libraries to directly return top N recommendations for users.

I just started to build my first recommender system project and was surprised to find how many libraries and tutorials end at something like

```
score = model.predict(user_id, item_id)
```

instead of providing a function to return top N recommendations for all users. I usually have to calculate the product of each user and item vector, update the scores for purchased items to -1 so they won't get selected, then partially rank the items for each user to return top N recommendations.

The reason I want this feature is I want to train my model offline and save the results to DB, which is fed to a dashboard. Saving just the model embeddings takes more storage and re-calculating the top N items for every user is too much latency.

Why is this process not widely modularized? Is there libraries out there that implemented this that I am not aware of or this is not a common practice?